# Java swing application launch - Certificate error

Tags: java, swing, ssl

Our application is java swing based application which was designed in java 1.6. We are currently trying to upgrade the application to be compatible with 1.7. We bought new certificate and configured in application as well. While launching application in 1.7, we are getting security warning alert as below

> Unable to ensure the certificate used to identify this application has not been revoked

Please help to resolve the problem.

Pls note : There is no problem with certificate (other applications are working good with the same certificate )

Comment: Normally this is configurable in an option in the Java Control Panel (if you're running Windows or Mac OS, it should be easy enough). Check [this link](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/revocation_options.xml) for detailed instructions.